# Python palindrome programming

Tags: python

The code is a bit messy, but the point is to divide it up into different functions.

I understand that you can test the palindrome but how do you use a Boolean variable, instead of stating straight away print function.

```
def trial():
    palindrome = True

    c = str(input("Hey: "))

    for i in range(len(c)):
        a = c[i]
        s = c[-(i+1)]
    if  (a == s):       
        return 
    break
    else:
        print ("No, its not a plaindrome")
    break

    return palindrom 

def output():
    print True


trial()
output()
```

Comment: It looks like your indentation is a bit off but you could just use `return True` or `return False`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `return` value within another function

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

def output(s):
    if isPalindrome(s):           # We use the return value of the above function
        print('it is a palindrome')
    else:
        print('not a palindrome')
```

For example

```
>>> output('hello')
not a palindrome

>>> output('abcba')
it is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

A little background on your programming idea - I call it (and probably others as well) *the witness*. What does it mean? It means that we assume somethnig is `True` - until we're proved to be wrong. This is also true in modern courts when someone is innocent unless proven guilty.

Now let's see the code:

```
# let's go on to the trial!
def trial():
    # the string is a palindrome, or "innocent" (this is redundant in this case)
    palindrome = True
    c = str(input("Hey: "))

    # this iterates the string twice, you actually need half
    # but that's only an optimization.
    for i in range(len(c)):
        a = c[i]
        s = c[-(i+1)]
        # if we found characters that are not mirrored - this is not a palindrome.
        # these are our witnesses!
        if  (a != s):        
            return False # naive: palindrome = False
    # we've gone over the string and found no witnesses to say it's "guilty"
    return True # naive: return palindrome
```

Remember that when using this style, you only care about the "guilty" part, and then you can immediately `return`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simpler way to check for palindromes:

```
def is_palindromic(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

And then use the return value in the if statement.

```
if is_palindromic(s):
    print "Yay!"
else:
    print "Too bad"
```